# Como faço um alert?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu quando carrego num botão, sera q e possível aparecer uma caixa de dialogo com os botões sim ou não?Se carregasse no sim ia para um lado se carregasse no não ficava na página.
É possível?

Comment: Poderia postar  o que já tentou?

Comment: Você utiliza bootstrap ou algum framework de criação dos formulários?

Comment: O que tem por padrão nos browsers é `var resposta = confirm("Confirma a operação?")`, com botões OK e Cancelar. Fora isso, é na unha mesmo ou com algum framework.

Comment: Não utilizo nenhum bootstrap nem framework

Comment: Eu naõ fiz nada porque não sei por onde começar

Comment: ao meu entender ele que um confirm. Se clicar em sim redireciona para uma página se não fica na  atual.

Comment: Sim eu quero isso, podem-me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da forma tradicional via javascript. Porem as opção são fixas para ok ou cancelar, já que o `confirm` é implementado internamente em cada navegador.

```
<script>
    confirma() {
        if (confirm('Deseja realmente fazer determinada ação?')) {
            // código caso tenha confirmado
        } else {
            // código caso tenha cancelado
        }
    }
</script>

<button onClick="cofirma();"> Botão de confirmação <button>
```

Se não atender ao que quer, já que é algo bem mais especifico, recomendo procurar por uma solução via um plugin, como no caso os modais do Bootstrap.

Comment: Ao carregar no butao é supoto fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Acho clicar no botão, vai acionar a função do javascript. O if nada mais que interpreta o sim ou não. Isso que queria saber?

Comment: Sim era.Mas como faço para aparecer uma caixa a dizer"sim ou não"?

Comment: Por padrão, o `confirm` da apenas as opção de ok ou cancelar, não dando a opção de modificar os nomes por ser codificados já no navegador.

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves essa resposta pode ser util.

Comment: Mas ao carregar no ok, ele pode ir para um link,pagina?

Comment: Sim, basta implementar dentro do `if`  `window.location = 'urlDesejada'`

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, pode fazer desta maneira:

```
if (confirm('Deseja mudar de pagina?')) {
     window.location.href='http://google.com';
} else {
    // fica na pagina
}
```

Você pode usar javascript, pode olhar esse [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp), e nesse [aqui tem um exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2)

Comment: É possivel ao carregar no ok e ir para uma página?

Comment: Rafael não dês respostas só com links pf. Dá exemplos e explica como fazer o que o AP precisa.

Comment: é possivel sim... pode fazer desta maneira

`if (confirm('Deseja mudar de pagina?')) {
            window.location.href='http://google.com';
        } else {
            // fica na pagina
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `confirm` que é nativa nos browsers. Ela retorna `true` ou `false` de acordo com a resposta do usuário.

```
if (confirm('Deseja ir para a página de configurações?')) {
    window.location.href = 'config.php';
}
```